# Understanding Redux Architecture Pattern(s)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been learning React/Redux and am attempting to build an base app which would sit in an application suite.

I am having some trouble getting my head around the "correct" architecture for such an application or whether I'm even approaching it in a redux way. At a basic level I want something like:

App Main ---> Application ToolBar --> Logout Button

So these would essentially represent my react components. My Main has a toolbar which has a logout button. But how do I correctly implement the logout function? I seem to be finding conflicting implementations in the examples I look up.

One way I have seen passes functions down from the App main (which is in charge of application's logged in state). So I would do:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <ToolBar logout="() => { this.logout(); }"/>
</Provider>
```

In my app component and declare it in the props of my ToolBar component to be called on logout click. But this seems really anti-patternish to me because in a large application I'm just going to end up with parent level functions being passed down through chains of children and it's going to get very messy quickly.

So another possible answer is to dispatch actions? Then my Toolbar component will do:

```
<button onClick={ () => {this.props.store.dispatch(MY_LOGOUT_ACTION());} } />
```

With the App component then consuming the action and performing a logout. If this is correct, what is the correct code for consuming the action on the parent side?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Components don't need to dispatch actions directly (they don't see `store` or `dispatch` at all). They simply get redux state passed in as props via `mapStateToProps` and can call actions (also props, but functions) via `mapDispatchToProps`. Your Toolbar can be rendered as just `<Toolbar>` and will receive the necessary redux bindings by being a connected component.

Comment: @timotgl And this is done via mapDispatchToProps? So my action has to be declared in ToolBar's  mapDispatchToProps function? How do I then perform the dispatch?

Comment: The actions are usually declared in a separate module. The module where you're creating the connected component imports them. So it's `const mapDispatchToProps = { action };`, and the connected component simply calls `this.props.action()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[react-router](https://reacttraining.com/)** as well.Below code related to react-router@3.x version. The latest version is 4.

**Step 1** - Manage your routes

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route path="toolbar" component={toolbar} onEnter={ensureUserLoggedIn}>
        <!-- Any sub routes-->
        <Route path="toolbarsub1/:id" component={sub1} />
    </Route>
</Provider>
```

**Step 2** - Some function to check if the user is authenticated

```
ensureUserLoggedIn = () => /* return true or false based on ur Auth/Cookie/Local storage usage, if the user is logged in or not*/
```

**Step 3**

You login and logout are actions despatched to redux.

Sampe user.actions.js

```
export const logOutUser = () => ({
  type: LOGOUT_USER,
});

export const logInUser = (creds) => ({
  type: LOGIN_USER,
  creds,
});
```

Make sure once the logInUser action is dispatched, the function **ensureUserLoggedIn**  should return false if called.

This should be ideal login/logout architecture using redux.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you are going a step ahead of me. I am not asking specifically about logging in/out of an application, it's just an example.

What I'm asking about is the correct way for two components to communicate when the child needs to inform the parent container of some user input (for example clicking a logout button).

Comment: If the child needs to send some info to parent component then.

OuterComponent.jsx
--------------------------

const updateSomeData = (data) => {
 console.log('Data reached outer component');
} 
render (<OuterComponent>
 <InnerComponet callback={this.updateSomeData}>
</OuterComponent>);

InnerComponet.jsx


render (<Div>
 <span onClick={e => this.props.callback}>
</Div>);

Comment: Thank you, what is the "this" in this.updateSomeData when your function is declared as a const?

Comment: There are 2 ways you can bind a function in a React class, which is important if you don't bind then the callers 'this' would 

prevail over the 'this' of the React component, which is not desirable.

Way 1. In constuctor --------------
MyComp extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
 this.state = {},
 thus.updateSomeData = this.updateSomeData.bind.this();
 }
}

Way 2: Using ES6 short hand function, not mentioning in constructor ----------------

MyComp extends React.Component {
const = updateSomeData(inputdata) => console.log('Data reached outer component');

}